# How do I insert spaces within a razor Code block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

VS2013, MVC5, Razor, VB

I want spaces in front of the word 'Answered'.  How do I force spaces into the following Razor code block?

```
@Code If Model.DisplayAnsweredFlag Then
  @If Model.Answered Then
    @Html.Raw("Answered")
   End If
 End If
End Code
```

In html.raw(), spaces by themselves or spaces in of front text don't seem to get coded into the page.  But I also can't use '&nbsp' or '@&nbsp' in a Code Block because it's incorrect syntax.

If I'm coding with a poor technique, please advise, or if there is a different way to get the spaces in, please advise.

Comment: try adding spaces surround the <text> tags i.e: @Html.Raw("Answered")<text>&nbsp</text>

Comment: most likely you should handle this by adding padding to the tag that contains the text.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Spaces are ignored when parsing HTML, unless they occur within a `pre` block. If you want to pad some text, you need to take one of the following approaches:

1. Wrap it in a block-level HTML element like `p` or `div`, and then add padding/margin to the element using CSS. This is the recommended approach.
2. Use `&nbsp;` in place of the regular spaces you're trying to pad with. Only non-breaking spaces are counted when rendering HTML. However, this approach is hacky and not recommended.
3. Wrap your text in a `pre` element. Then all whitespace within the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags will be taken into account. However, this approach is also hacky and not recommended.

Comment: The <div> and <p> worked well.  The <pre> cranked in unexpected formatting; would that likely be defined in the bootstrap.css files?  I also noticed the <p> added some vertical spacing where the <div> did not, so I went with <div style="padding-left: 50px">.

Comment: I used `<span>@Html....</span><span>@Html....</span>` in order to display two elements seperated by space.

Answer (score 39):

**AndyBuk** gave the answer here:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1772048.aspx?How+to+use+no+break+space+HTML+character+inside+if+brackets+in+a+view+

In that link he writes:

> The introduction to Razor syntax at:
>   http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax
>   is quite useful.
> To force html output for your string, you may use `<text>` to Block or `@:` as a Prefix.

```
@if (condition)
{
    <text>&nbsp;</text>
    @:&nbsp;
}
```

Comment: Question asks clearly for a VB.net approach, also is tagged as VB.net

Comment: Hello @kpull1 While the Questioner mentions and does tag they are using VB for their coding, it doesn't matter as the solution I pasted uses **Razor** syntax (meaning it doesn't matter if you use it inside a C# **_or_** VB.net code block).  The Questioner even mentions they are using Razor and tried using `@&nbsp` and my Answer shows Alan he was _so_ close; he just needed `@:&nbsp;` instead or he could have typed up his Raw HTML inside of the **Razor** (_not_ C# or VB.net) `<text>` Element.

Comment: I just meant that the `if` block should be written in VB.net syntax.

Answer (score 9):

```
<text> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</text>
```

Insert "`&nbsp;`" to add more blank spaces.

Comment: This works, but how would I go about this if I'm using sort if statements? Like so;

(condition ? "output me" : <text>This will not work</text>)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try a different approach.  Use a span tag with some padding on it

Comment: That worked well, but I elected to go with the <div> as below.

Answer (score 2):

I use this approach when I need to display a structure in the table.

The `item` has precalculated the `level` property.

```
@helper PrintChild(List<ItemBalanceView> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Raw(InsertSpaces(item.LevelNum))<a class="text-primary" href='@Url.Content("~/Items/DetailsPos/")@item.ItemDocDetailID'>@item.ItemDocDetailName</a></td>
            <td>@Math.Round(item.Qty, 2)</td>
            <td>@Math.Round(item.Price, 2)</td>
            <td>@Math.Round(item.Total, 2)</td>
        </tr>

        if (item.Children != null)
        {
            @PrintChild(item.Children)
        }
    }
}

@functions  
{
    string InsertSpaces(int level)
    {
        var str = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
        {
            str += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }

        return str;
    }
}

<table class="table table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.BalancesAsStructure)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.Raw(InsertSpaces(item.LevelNum))<a class="text-primary" href='@Url.Content("~/Items/DetailsPos/")@item.ItemDocDetailID'>@item.ItemDocDetailName</a></td>
                <td>@Math.Round(item.Qty, 2)</td>
                <td>@Math.Round(item.Price, 2)</td>
                <td>@Math.Round(item.Total, 2)</td>
            </tr>

            if (item.Children != null)
            {
                @PrintChild(item.Children)
            }
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr style="background-color:#d7c0c0!important;">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>@Math.Round(Model.Total, 2)</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```